# AVG of number of operations per day for each shop

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a table with operations_id,  date and shop_number.
I need to create calculated field which shows AVG of number of operations per day for each shop.
How can I create it?

Comment: Need more information as the answer can depend on what you have in your rows/columns. What is the desired result?

Comment: In particular, is the operation_id unique, I.e. never repeated?